# Writing from C program to named pipe to be read in bash script

Tags: c, pipe, ipc

I am trying to write from a C program to a named pipe, and read from that pipe in a bash script. I am using two terminals, running the c program first, then running the bash script. The bash script reads from the pipe, because once it does the C program becomes unblocked, but $line is always empty.

The only thing printed to the terminal is "done reading". I'm unsure why the value is empty.

Bash Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

pipe=/tmp/myfifo
    
if read line <$pipe; then
    echo $line
fi

echo "done reading"
```

C Program:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include <sys/stat.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <unistd.h>

void WritePipe()
{
    int fd1; 
  
    char * myfifo = "/tmp/myfifo"; 
  
    mkfifo(myfifo, 0666); 
    char s1[50] = "Hello From C++ Program";

    fd1 = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY); 
    
    write(fd1, s1, strlen(s1) + 1);

    
    close(fd1);
}

int main() 
{
    WritePipe();
    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: If you want to read lines in your Bash script, you need to write lines in your C program. This should work if you change `char s1[50] = "Hello From C++ Program";` to `char s1[50] = "Hello From C++ Program\n";` (where `\n` is a line break).

Comment: That was the problem, thanks!